# cannot figure out python sub

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to use python re module to replace, but it never works.
the bbb.conf can be different.conf. and I wanna replace it with another known file.
What am I doing wrong? Thank!

```
import re
foo = '<source>\n  @type syslog\n  port 5140\n  bind 0.0.0.0\n  @include /etc/aaa/bbb.conf\n  message_format auto\n  tag eeee\n  message_length_limit 16384\n</source>\n\n'

repl = '/etc/ccc/lg.json' 
res = re.sub(r'@include \/etc\/aaa\/\/S+.conf', repl, foo)
print(res)
```

Comment: Remove the ``/`` right before `S`: `r'@include /etc/aaa/\S+\.conf'`, see https://ideone.com/4QicKN

Answer (score 0):

It appears what you're trying to do is replace the portion of the multi-line string that looks like this:

```
@include /path/to/anything.conf
```

with this:

```
@include /etc/ccc/lg.json
```

though it's not clear if that's the goal because the replacement string doesn't contain `@include`.

If this is what you're trying to do, this would work:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=@include )\S+\.conf', repl, foo)
```

This would replace any sequence of non-whitespace characters, which ends in `.conf`, and is immediately preceded by `@include`  (with a space), with the filename in `repl`.

As an example:

```
'<source>\n  @type syslog\n  port 5140\n  bind 0.0.0.0\n  @include /etc/aaa/bbb.conf\n  message_format auto\n  tag eeee\n  message_length_limit 16384\n</source>\n\n'
```

becomes:

```
'<source>\n  @type syslog\n  port 5140\n  bind 0.0.0.0\n  @include /etc/ccc/lg.json\n  message_format auto\n  tag eeee\n  message_length_limit 16384\n</source>\n\n'
```